# Deleting realized instances with empty (in geometry nodes)

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to delete instances that are in contact with the empty object.
I've created the setup like below, but the biggest problem is that it only works for one object in contact at a time. Any ideas on how to fix it?
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

check this out:

[image]

[image]

First i store the instid so that i got this information at every point. You can check that if you connect the viewer after realize instances.
Then i accumulate the result of every distance separated by instance id.